# MPI_OP_Create function

Tags: mpi

I want write function, which will compare numbers from all processes and return minimal (number must be positive).

```
void findIndexForMinNorm(double *invec, double *inoutvec, int *, MPI_Datatype *){
   if(invec[0] > 0){
      if(inoutvec[0] > invec[0] || inoutvec[0] < 0){
         inoutvec[0] = invec[0];
        /*inoutvec[1] = invec[1];*/
      }
   }

}
```

inoutvec is common for all processes or not?

Comment: I think that the short answer is no. You will need to use one of MPI methods to share the data among the different processes.

Comment: but how the standard minimum function is implemented?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easiest to illustrate with some code. As Gilles explained, MPI will take care of all the communications and do the reduction across processes - all you need to specify is the pairwise comparison function. Note that the prototype for the reduction operation is fixed by MPI and allows for a vector reduction: the third argument is the count for the length of the vector on each process (*not* the number of processes which is implicitly the size of the communicator). Other than some minor issues with void vs double pointers your comparison function can be registered as-is and used for a reduction operation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

void findminnorm(void *invec, void *inoutvec, int *len, MPI_Datatype *datatype)
{
  int i;

  double *invecdble    = (double *) invec;
  double *inoutvecdble = (double *) inoutvec;

  for (i=0; i < *len; i++)
    {
      if (invecdble[i] > 0)
      {
        if (inoutvecdble[i] > invecdble[i] || inoutvecdble[i] < 0)
          {
            inoutvecdble[i] = invecdble[i];
          }
       }
    }
}


#define N 2

int main()
{
  int i;
  double input[N], output[N];

  int rank, size;
  MPI_Op MPI_MINNORM;

  MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  MPI_Op_create(findminnorm, 1, &MPI_MINNORM);

  for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
      input[i] = (-size/2+rank+i)*(i+1);
      printf("On rank %d,  input[%d] = %f\n", rank, i, input[i]);
      output[i] = -1;
    }

  MPI_Allreduce(&input, &output, N, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MINNORM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
      printf("On rank %d, output[%d] = %f\n", rank, i, output[i]);
    }

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The initialisation is a bit random but I think it serves to illustrate the point (although your comparison function should really cope with the situation where all inputs are negative):

```
mpirun -n 5 ./minnorm | grep input | sort
On rank 0,  input[0] = -2.000000
On rank 0,  input[1] = -2.000000
On rank 1,  input[0] = -1.000000
On rank 1,  input[1] = 0.000000
On rank 2,  input[0] = 0.000000
On rank 2,  input[1] = 2.000000
On rank 3,  input[0] = 1.000000
On rank 3,  input[1] = 4.000000
On rank 4,  input[0] = 2.000000
On rank 4,  input[1] = 6.000000

mpirun -n 5 ./minnorm | grep output | sort
On rank 0, output[0] = 1.000000
On rank 0, output[1] = 2.000000
On rank 1, output[0] = 1.000000
On rank 1, output[1] = 2.000000
On rank 2, output[0] = 1.000000
On rank 2, output[1] = 2.000000
On rank 3, output[0] = 1.000000
On rank 3, output[1] = 2.000000
On rank 4, output[0] = 1.000000
On rank 4, output[1] = 2.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

`inoutvec` is not common for all processes.

Your operation only have to compute `inoutvec = min(invec, inoutvec)` and the MPI library will take care of the communications and invoking your operator with the appropriate `inoutvec`.

From the MPI standard chapter 5.9.5 page 185:

> Advice to implementors. We outline below a naive and inefficient
>   implementation of MPI_REDUCE not supporting the `in place` option.
>
> ```
> MPI_Comm_size(comm, &groupsize);
> MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);
> if (rank > 0) {
> MPI_Recv(tempbuf, count, datatype, rank-1,...);
> User_reduce(tempbuf, sendbuf, count, datatype);
> }
> if (rank < groupsize-1) {
> MPI_Send(sendbuf, count, datatype, rank+1, ...);
> }
> /* answer now resides in process groupsize-1 ... now send to root
> */
> if (rank == root) {
> MPI_Irecv(recvbuf, count, datatype, groupsize-1,..., &req);
> }
> if (rank == groupsize-1) {
> MPI_Send(sendbuf, count, datatype, root, ...);
> }
> if (rank == root) {
> MPI_Wait(&req, &status);
> }
> ```